# How to properly start Linux services with ansible shell module inline?

Tags: shell, ansible, inline, systemctl

I'm trying to use ansible shell module in order to start a bunch of services on RHEL hosts. It works well with systemctl stop and status and lies with the start one...

```sh
ansible all -i "host1,host2," -m shell -a "systemctl start example-service" -u priv-user -K
```

Actually, it starts a service for 3-4s or so and outputs pid of the process, which goes down eventually.

So, some services manage to survive with the line below. Anyway, this trick is not universal...

```sh
ansible all -i "host1,host2," -m shell -a "systemctl start example-service; sleep 10" -u priv-user -K
```

I know playbooks can cover it with no problem with async and poll. However, I prefer to use shell module inline to quickly fix or check some minor stuff.

Comment: By "nix", do you mean "Unix"? (I was trying to figure out what your question had to do with [`nix`](https://www.nixos.org).)

Comment: Yeah, sry for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `shell` module for that is very bad practice. You should use the `service` or `systemd` (as you are using systemd) module.

```sh
ansible all -i "host1,host2," -m systemd -a "name=example-service state=started" -u priv-user -K
```

Or with `service`:

```sh
ansible all -i "host1,host2," -m service -a "name=example-service state=started" -u priv-user -K
```

Documentation of the [service](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html) and [systemd](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html) modules.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need

Comment: @MikeWazowski great! Please consider accepting my answer by clicking the gray check-mark next to it :)